# Javascript - How do I get the click action applied only do the upper level element

Tags: javascript, html, css, r, shiny

I have the following HTML code generated with ShinyR that corresponds to 2 collapsible boxes one inside the other.

```
<div class="box box-info collapsed-box">
          <div class="box-header">
                    <h3 class="box-title">
                             <div>Title</div>
                    </h3>
                    <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                              <button class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse">
                                           <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                               </button>
                    </div>
           </div>
           <div class="box-body" id="idtolocate" style="display: none;">
                     <div class="col-sm-100%">
                               <div class="box box-warning collapsed-box">
                                         <div class="box-header">
                                                   <h3 class="box-title">
                                                            <div>SubTitle</div>
                                                   </h3>
                                                   <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                                                      <button class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                                                      </button>
                                                    </div>
                                         </div>
                                         <div class="box-body" id="idSubToLocate" style="display: none;">
                                         </div>
                                </div>
                      </div>
           </div>
</div>
```

What I would like the following javascript to do is to expand only the box at the same level (without going at all the sublevels - what unfortunately the find function does)

```
$('#' + boxid).parent('.box'>'.box-tools pull-right').find('[data-widget=collapse]').click();
```

so that when boxid is idtolocate only the upper box is expanded, if it is idSubtolocate the inner box is expanded instead.

It is not a problem if the inner box gets expanded and it is not visible because the outer box is collapsed.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```js
$('.btn-box-tool').click(function(){console.log('click on '+$('i',this).text())});

$('#xtra').click(function(){ 
  let boxid='idSubToLocate';
  let btn=$('#' + boxid).closest('.box')
          .find('[data-widget=collapse]').click();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box box-info collapsed-box">
  <div class="box-header">
    <h3 class="box-title">
      <div>Title</div>
    </h3>
    <div class="box-tools pull-right">
      <button class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse">
        <i class="fa fa-plus">one</i>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-body" id="idtolocate" style="display: nnone;">
    <div class="col-sm-100%">
      <div class="box box-warning collapsed-box">
        <div class="box-header">
          <h3 class="box-title">
            <div>SubTitle</div>
          </h3>
          <div class="box-tools pull-right">
            <button class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse">
              <i class="fa fa-plus">two</i>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box-body" id="idSubToLocate" style="display: none;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<button id="xtra">remote click on "idSubToLocate" button ==> two</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I simply added .first() in the result of the find function to make it work so that it restricts the click action only on the first objects that matches, that always happens to be the closest one.

```
$('#' + boxid).parent('.box').find('[data-widget=collapse]').first().click();
```